# Ques about JavaScript object.constructor property

Tags: javascript, constructor

1. Is there any possibility of `anyObject.constructor` property being null or undefined(especially when ConstructorFunc.prototype is not modified/overwritten)?
2. `var date = new Date(); console.log(date.constructor);` // logs "Date()". ok, fine. 
   `var data = new Array(1, 2, 3); console.log(data.constructor);` // it logs something like [ undefined ]. What is it and why is not Array().

TIA

Comment: `var data = new Array(1, 2, 3); console.log(data.constructor);` shows me `function Array() { [native code] }`. Which platform are you using? See the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8XVS/).

Comment: hmm.. yes, more confusion. If I try the same code in firebug console, it logs [ undefined].

Comment: @Arjun: Don't rely too heavily on console output. It's an interpretation, and is prone to errors and misinterpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, you can manually overwrite the `.constructor` property of a constructor function's `prototype` object.
2. It seems that the `constructor` property has been changed. Normally you'd probably see something like `function Array() { [native code] }` instead of `[ undefined ]`.

One thing you can do to verify is...

```
console.log(typeof [].constructor);
```

It should give you `"function"`. If it gives you `"object"`, then it's been changed.

---

***Don't trust console output***

It seems from a comment that you're testing in Firebug.

As a general rule *do not* put too much trust in console logging. Consoles are addons to the environment, and must *interpret* what they've been given to log. Sometimes the interpretation is misleading.

If you get odd results, then perform other tests...

```
console.log(Array);          // [ undefined ] ...huh???
console.log([].constructor); // [ undefined ] ...huh???

typeof [].constructor; // Firebug still gives "function"

[].constructor === Array; // Firebug returns true
```

So you can see that even though Firebug gave an odd interpretation of the function itself, it doesn't change the fact that it is still the expected `Array` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `constructor` property is `writable`. Hence `anyObject.constructor` can be explicitly set to `undefined` or `null` (this will create a new property on `anyObject` and won't modify the `constructor` property of the `prototype`). You may also change the `constructor` property of the `prototype` to `null` or `undefined` so that it's reflected on every instance of the function. By default it'll never be `null` or `undefined`.
2. It shows me `function Array() { [native code] }` as expected. Since you don't get the same result perhaps `Array.prototype.constructor` has been modified by some third party code. You should check that.